# Twitter API complaining that "Narrowcast id params must be integers."

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I'm using the Twitter npm module and when posting to `favorites/destroy.json` or `favorites/create.json` with something like

```
favorites/destroy.json?id=800364979287425024
```

I get `{ code: 96, message: 'Narrowcast id params must be integers.' }`. Does anyone have any idea what is going on? Twitter API documentation has nothing about it.

I tried sending the id with and without quotes and no luck.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that I was sending the `id` as a query parameter, not in the POST body. The [Twitter documentation for the route](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/favorites/destroy) has incorrect example code that uses query parameters instead of post body.

A body like this works.

```
{ id: 800364979287425024 }
```